# Как заменить символы в строке по ранее данному коду?

Tags: c++

Задача функции поменять **n** символов в строке **str**, начиная с позиции **beg** так, чтобы они располагались в порядке, который прописан в массиве **code**

Мой код функции

```
inline void replace(char *str, int beg, int *code, int n){
   int t = 0;
   while(t<n){
         if(code[t] != t){
                    char j;
                    j = str[beg + t];
                    str[beg + t] = str[beg + t + code[t]];
                    str[beg + t + code[t]] = j;     
         }  
         t++;
   }
```

}

Вызываю функцию так:

```
replace (&message[0], n, &code[0], code_n);
```

Подскажите, в чём ошибка, отладчик выдаёт ошибку сегментации в этом месте:

```
 str[beg + t] = str[beg + t + code[t]];
```

Понятия не имею, в чём загвоздка, думаю на некорректные аргументы.

Comment: @mrexox, так посмотрите значения всех аргументов в отладчике.

Comment: К примеру:
На ввод идёт 
ILOVEYOU
67854231

Выводится
UYOEVILO

Comment: @mrexox, вообще-то массивы (и символы в строках) а Си индексируются с 0.

Поэтому числа в `code[]` должны быть в интервале `0 : n-1`. 

Но валится у Вас из-за того, что `[beg + t + code[t]]` для больших `t` явно вылезает за границу `str`.

Если Вы хотите обменять местами 2 символа в str где-то в интервале от `beg` до `beg + n`, то надо писать

         j = str[beg + t];
         str[beg + t] = str[beg + code[t]];
         str[beg + code[t]] = j;

Но работать все равно будет неверно. Тут нужен более хитрый алгоритм. 

Думаю как-то надо по ходу замен модифицировать значения в `code[]`.

Comment: Самый же простой способ это завести в начале `replace` буфер размером `n` символов и заполнить его символами, начиная с `str[beg + t]` по индексам `code[t]`.

А потом скопировать его обратно в `str`.

Хотя, я думаю, это у Вас учебное задание и такой простой способ не подойдет.

Answer (score 2):

Вы, вероятно, инициализируете свой указатель строковым литералом. При попытке изменить содержимое строки вы получаете вышеуказанное исключение (либо знаменитый access violation, если речь о VC++). Чтобы избежать этого, объявите строку как массив: 
То есть не так:

```
char* chr = "qwerty";
```

а вот так:

```
char chr[] = "qwerty";
```

Comment: увы dev c++, строка объявлена как и вы советуете

Comment: @mrexox, ну если не дружите с отладчиком, так printf поставьте перед местом где валиться.

--

А что следует понимать под

    ... так, чтобы они располагались в порядке, который прописан в массиве code

???

Вы бы хоть парочку примеров с исходными данными и правильным результатом привели.